# Check content of multiple variables using for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, arguments, var

I have multiple array variables that contain a question, and two answer options. They are used for a survey that changes questions.

```
var q1 = ["question","option1","option2"];
var q2 = ["question","option1","option2"];
...
var q8 = ["","",""];
var q9 = ["","",""];
```

I want to be able to change the amount of questions the user goes through, automatically. The way I will do this is by adding a for-loop that checks if the array is empty or not, and if the array is empty, it will finish the survey on the question before.

Here is what I tried:

```
for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    if ("q"+i = ["","",""]) {
        console.log("Stopped at "+i);
        finishSurvey():
        i = 9; //Stop for-loop
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
}
```

The problem here is the left side of the if-argument, I also tried this:

```
if (qi = ["","",""]) {
```

However it will then choose the first available option (1). Using == or === makes qi undefined. How can I check all the array variables for being empty, with a for-loop? I would need a way to increase the second digit every time the loop runs, and then have it read as a variable.

I could do it with a long if-sentence, but if I were to have more questions then it would be a pain.

Comment: "*I have multiple variables*" - there's your problem. Never use variables with enumerated names - use an array instead, like `var q = [q1, q2, q3, …];` You then can easily iterate this array of questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really 'dynamically' loop over variables like that.  I would try throwing all the questions in one array and putting each one along with their answers in an object:

```
<div id="root"></div>


var questions = [
  {
    question: "question 1",
    answers: [
      "answer 1",
      "answer 2"
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "question 2",
    answers: [
      "answer 1",
      "answer 2"
    ]
  },
   {
    question: "question 3",
    answers: [
      "answer 1",
      "answer 2"
    ]
  }
];


function renderQuestions(questionsArr) {
   var html = '';
   var container = document.getElementById("#root");

   quesaionsArr.forEach(function(questionObj) {
     if (questionObj.question && questionObj.answers.length) {
       // do your work to create each question and answer 
     }
   }); 

   // append final html to parent
   container.appendChild(html)
}
```

Comment: This use of arrays is way to complicated for me to understand. Your code also gives a syntax error.

Comment: "You can't really 'dynamically' loop over variables like that" -- You s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶n̶e̶v̶e̶r could always use `eval()` to reach that kind of functionality.

Comment: I don't know how you're generating the questions, but an array would be how I would do it.  I've added a little more code for you to play with...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the content of the array to see whether it contains empty strings, for that I used `join` to append all the empty strings and make it into one and then compare with a empty string reference.

Once we find an empty string occurrence, we stop and come out of the loop and print the ith question where we encountered the empty array. Assuming you are passing the question arrays in an ordered way, such that the question array having empty strings is at the end.

```js
var q1 = ["question","option1","option2"];
var q2 = ["question","option1","option2"];
var q3 = ["","",""];
var q4 = ["","",""];
var questions = [q1, q2, q3, q4];

function checkQuestions(questions){
 for(let i =0; i<questions.length;i++){
   if(questions[i].join("") === ""){
      console.log("stopped at question "+(i+1));
      break;
    }
  } 
}
checkQuestions(questions);
```

Comment: Alright, but the variables are still mentioned one by one. Is this is only way?

Comment: @Marcus you can pass any number of variables, i am taking them from the `arguments` array. You could also pass an array of variables to the function and use the spread operator. `checkQuestions(...[q1, q2, q3, q4]);`.

Comment: No, don't use `eval` for this.

Comment: Much better, although I don't see any reason to use spread syntax here and the `arguments` object. Either just pass the `q` array as a single parameter, or use rest syntax and call `checkQuestions(q1, q2, q3, q4)`. Thanks for the edit!